# Where to apply grease apart from pad ears?

Tags: brakes

When greasing the brake pad itself with something like copper-based grease, where exactly do you apply it? (I don't wish to discuss the type of grease here, I'm aware copper-based has fallen out of favour recently. I also don't want to talk about silicone based grease for slider pins. I just want to identify precisely where we apply the appropriate type of grease to the *pad*)

Comment: Anywhere, where there is metal on metal contact. So the back where piston makes contact to avoid noise, and the ends which slide in the stainless guides as lube for movement